# Python Selenium, find span in the button

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I wasted a lot of time to figure out why driver does not want to click on this button. I believe that someone can help me to solve this problem. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIYFT.jpg)

I need to click "Enter password".

I am so tired. I have been trying to find out the reason of the one for more than 10hrs, but I still cannnot. I checked a lot of threads about Selenium, xpath, span and etc. I've tried to start up this finder with execute_script(), but it still could not and can not find this button and click this.

website: https://e.mail.ru/login?email=

```html
self.driver.find_element_by_id("//span[@class='inner-1-1-75 innerTextWrapper-1-1-76']")
"//span[contains(text(), 'Enter password')]//parent::button"
/span[contains(.,'Enter password')]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
driver.get('https://e.mail.ru/login?email=')

frame = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "iframe"))
)

driver.switch_to_frame(frame)

password = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-test-id=\"next-button\"]"))
)
password.click()
driver.switch_to_default_content()
```

Its inside an iframe , you should switch to it to interact with it , and once done you have to switch back ot outer frame by using switch to defaul content for being able to interact again with elements outside the iframe.

use explicit waits also to avoid loading issues

Comment: Thanks for your answer. frame = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.TAG_NAME, "iframe"))
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: ohhh. srry, im so stupid. I read your advice again and test like driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe")) then I tried to find "Enter password" in driver.page_source cuz of when I took this one and tried to find, I got nothing. Thank you.

Comment: @rinate please accepth the answer by clicking the tick sign enar to the answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the website. And I think that's not difficult.
You are using wrong method. You need to use find_element_by_xpath method.

I am a ruby developer, so would like to write ruby script.

```
next_button = driver.find_element(:xpath, "//button[@data-test-id='next-button']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", next_button)
```

In my opinion, your xpath is not correct

```
xpath = "//button[@data-test-id='next-button']"
```

I think that's enough

Below is full answer written in python script

```
next_button = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@data-test-id='next-button']")
self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", next_button)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried this xpath, but it still does not work.